# Is there anything shared between instances that I can use to store and share some values?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a password that my appservice use to connect to another backend service. Originally I've saved the password on the appsettings since it is shared between instances when the app service scales out and it is accessible if I want to change it or check the connection from my system.

Now there is another task on my desk to change the password on the fly every week. What would be the best place to store the password and update it?

- **App settings:**

  I'm not sure if it is even possible to write a code in C# to update the Appsettings, I might need to write it in powershell or something but even if I could it would recycle the application
- **Database:**

  In a sense DB is common and shared between instances and accessible by DBA, but it seems strange to have a table and store just 1 value in it. Besides the nature of this data is totally different from my applications data, so if this is the solution I'm not going to store it in another DB, which means 1DB to store 1 row in 1 table!
- **Azure specific key store**

  Is there any keystore in Azure that I can manupulate with my C# code and save data?
- **Any other solution?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/) for storing centrally managed "secrets" that need to be mananged and audited when accessed.

Some of the main features for Key Vault are:

- Safe place for key/secret storage
- Centralized storage
- Lifetime management for keys/secrets
- User/Group management for access to secrets
- Automatic rotation of secrets
- Possibility to use a hardware security modules for storage

The other options you listed would technically also work, but in my opinion, when you are dealing with secrets the best alternative is Key Vault.

See, e.g. this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/key-vault?view=azure-dotnet for a quick intro into Azure Key Vault usage with C# applications